# How to change the git command-line language to Dutch?

Tags: git, command-line, locale

Running git from my xterm on i3wm on Debian results in English text output. The environment variables `LANG` and `LC_ALL` are set to `nl_NL.UTF-8` but do not seem to have any effect on this output. The Dutch locale `nl_NL.UTF-8` is installed.

I have tried to reinstall git, and run `sudo apt upgrade`, both to no avail; running `LANG=nl_NL git` also still results in English text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git [doesn't appear to have a Dutch translation](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/po), so it falls back to English.

Comment: @user3F31A28 You could be a contributor!

Comment: Yeah, that sounds nice, I've always wanted to contribute to open source projects